# Aggregating list items of duplicate rows in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe with a key column and a list column:

```
   Key    List
0  K1  [A, B]
1  K1     [C]
```

I want to aggregate the lists of rows where `Key` is the same, i.e.:

```
  Key       List
0  K1  [A, B, C]
```

The order of the list items does *not* matter for my purposes. The `Key` column should be unique after the operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` with flatten values in lambda function:

```
import functools
import operator

from  itertools import chain

f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
#faster alternative
#f = lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))
#faster alternative2
#f = lambda x: functools.reduce(operator.iadd, x, [])
#slow alternative
#f = lambda x: x.sum()
df = df.groupby('Key')['List'].agg(f).reset_index()
```

Another slow alternative:

```
df = df.groupby('Key')['List'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I don't think `as_index` should be False. With `as_index=False` I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (1, 1)` while `as_index=True` gives the expected output.

Comment: @tsorn - Thank you, added `.reset_index()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key': ['K1', 'K1'],
    'List': [['A', 'B'], ['C'],]
})
```

Which looks like:

```
    Key List
0   K1  [A, B]
1   K1  [C]
```

You can use:

```
df.groupby('Key').agg({'List': 'sum'})
```

Which gives you:

```
    List
Key 
K1  [A, B, C]
```